# Install Intel Graphics HD 3000 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have installed Windows Server 2012 on my laptop which has an Intel Core i3 330UM Arrandale CPU and HD graphics (revision 18).

The graphics get installed as *Microsoft Basic Graphics Adaptor* and I cannot change the resolution from 1024x768. I have tried installing the Intel drivers but they say that my system does not meet the minimum requirements.

I would like to be able to increase the resolution and gain hardware acceleration, how can I install the Intel drivers?

Answer (score 3):

I have two possible solutions for you.

1) You could try to run the installer in compatibility mode with Windows 7/8 (I'm assuming here that you have downloaded the Windows 7/8 version). This may or may not fool the installer into thinking that it is a Windows 7/8 machine (it really depends on how Intel checks the Windows version).

2) If the first suggestion does not work, you can manually install the driver using Device Manager. You can do this by starting the Device Manager, right-clicking on *Microsoft Basic Graphics Adapter*, and selecting "Properties". Next, click the "Driver" tab, then click "Update Driver...". Point to where you extracted the Intel Graphics installer, for example C:\IntelGraphics\win64_15288\Graphics. Then click next. Windows should find and install the driver for you automatically.

Let me know how it goes through the comments :)

**EDIT:** I would like you to try drivers I have found for 2nd Generation Core i3-based servers from Lenovo (this is MEANT for Server 2008 R2 64-Bit). They offer a driver package that should support Intel HD 2000 graphics, I'm hoping that this driver will also work for HD 3000 or at least let you change resolutions. Here is the link: http://support.lenovo.com/en_IN/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS030824

Here is a link if you have an Ivy Bridge processor (you didn't specify in your question): http://support.lenovo.com/en_IN/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS024887

This driver is meant for the Lenovo ThinkServer TS130 if you wish to find the page manually on Lenovo's support site.

Comment: I had initially tried both methods and neither worked (sorry should have mentioned this), but I think they might with some further tweaking. I followed some guides but they seem to be slightly out of date and don't work with the newer Intel drivers. (1) Editing Setup.if2 I could only find 3 and not 6 lines : http://www.win2008workstation.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=2139
 (2) igdlh64.inf not sure how to edit the latest version for 2012 http://www.neowin.net/news/how-to-install-legacy-intel-hd-graphics-drivers-on-windows-8#comment-1924181

Comment: Please refer to my edit!

Comment: @row1 Any news on this issue? I'm curious to know if the Lenovo driver is a viable option.

Comment: Unfortunately the installer fails to complete and the drivers it did copy cannot be manually applied.

Comment: My apologies, it seems like my HD graphics are actually 1st gen.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a known driver issue with Server 2012, that might maybe be solved in the future (or not).

To work around this issue, you might try to set the screen resolution by :

1. Access the **Advanced** setting in the Display Control Panel.
2. **List All Modes** in the Adapter tab.
3. Uncheck the **Hide modes that this monitor cannot display** checkbox in the Monitor tab.
4. Choose your resolution

Comment: List all modes only shows 1024x768 and lower. The 'Hide modes...' option checkbox is greyed out.

Comment: You could try to add a resolution using [PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm). You could also try other (older) drivers.

Comment: Not sure that older drivers will help. The problem seems to be that the driver packages are blocking Server 2012 as they only officially support 2008.

Comment: Officially there were no changes in drivers from Windows 7/2008R2 to 8/2012, but practically sometimes the drivers are not fully compatible. But this is worth trying still. Also PowerStrip.

Comment: It seems though either the installer or .inf file doesn't recognise  the Windows version as a supported one (or explicitly blocks 2012) and prevents you from proceeding.

Comment: Installer of PowerStrip? You could force it using right-click/Properties/Compatibility, but take a system restore point first because forced installs can sometimes be troublesome.

Comment: Sorry referring to your comment about using older drivers. I would like to avoid using PowerStrip as I actually want the intel drivers installed.

Comment: PowerStrip is not a driver - it adds custom profiles to the monitor but uses the existing drivers.

Comment: That's fine, but I actually want the intel drivers installed if possible.

Comment: Not a problem with PowerStrip - have a look at it.

Comment: PowerStrip wouldn't let me increase the resolution any further and it also frequently crashed. I assume it also wouldn't add hardware accelerated graphics, something that I would like.

Comment: If PowerStrip won't do it, then I think that the problem is with the driver, so you absolutely need to identify your on-board adapter. If you cannot find it in Device Manager, perhaps one of [these utilities](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-system-information-utility.htm). Or maybe even [UnknownDevices](http://code.google.com/p/unknowndevices/) might apply here.

Comment: The adaptor is in the OP, but no drivers can be installed because they say they say that Windows 2012 is not supported. This is the problem that I have the bounty for.

Comment: Have you tried [The Intel Driver Update Utility](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect?iid=dc_iduu)? And what model exactly is your laptop?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to get Windows Server 2012 on a Dell E6500 to load the Intel 4 series Express set
Downloaded the latest Windows 7 64 bit drivers and install them to the point you get the doesn't meet requirements error. This extracts the files under c:\Dell.

Go into the graphics folder and find the INF file and open it with notepad.

example: C:\Dell\Drivers\1M8J9\Graphics
 INF file was named d2869-64.inf

Find these lines

[IntelGfx.NTamd64.5.1]
; no install on XP

[IntelGfx.NTamd64.6.2]
; no install on Win8

[IntelGfx.NTamd64.6.0]

Change the 0 on the last line to 2. This makes it work on Windows 8 OR Windows Server 2012

But you are not done, you have just broken the digitally signed driver hash that is in the cat file, thus it will not match and when you click on the inf file and select install you will get a hash error and it WILL NOT INSTALL.

Now ready your machine for a restart and go to the lower right hand corner of your screen and expose the charms and click on settings go to the bottom and select change PC settings entry, select General, go to the bottom and select "Restart Now" Follow the directions, when the system comes up it will give you a list of options, pick disable Driver Signing and let the system come up.

Then go to your modified INF file right click on it and pick install, acknowledge the warning that the driver is unsigned. It installs and if you are doing what I was doing your dual monitors connected to a dell docking station with a Dell E6500 laptop docked in it immediately worked!

Glory and Victory and 3 hours of my life that I will never get back. Use this technique at your own risk, although I am working without blue screens so far there is not guarantee that this won't break your system.  Be careful out there.

Thanks to the many google postings on this issue that led me to the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been wrestling with a nearly identical problem (I wanted HD 4000 drivers). The solution turned out to be really simple: Intel offer the driver download in two forms: an .exe and a .zip. The .exe checks the OS version and won't install but the .zip version will happily install on Windows Server 2012.

Hopefully the situation is the same for 3000.